# Android: Unable to setText in Custom ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have created a custom ListView with 2 ImageView and a TextView.

In the Adapter, I'm doing setText in TextView, but it is not visible in the app.

Here is my List:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#289FA5"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#289FA5">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Popular products"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:padding="7dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pop_pro_men"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#289FA5">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Catagories"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:padding="7dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/cata_men"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
```

Here is my Custom List:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/custom_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="130dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#ffffff">


<ImageView
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:src="@drawable/clothing_men"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cata_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Clothing"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="27sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/forward_arrow"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"/>
```

And Here is the getView method of my Adapter:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Holder holder = new Holder();
    View rowView;

    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_subcatagory_list, null,true);

    TextView sub_catagory= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cata_name);
    ImageView pic = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    sub_catagory.setText(catagory[position]);
    pic.setImageResource(image[position]);
    Log.d("Strings========", sub_catagory.getText().toString());

    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + catagory[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}
```

Please Help as i am unable to find what is wrong in this.

Comment: Debug and check if catagory[position] is empty.

Comment: @Code_Yoga, i checked it, text is avaiable in Log, clickListener is showing Toast with Text...

Comment: okay, what are your returning in the getCount() method in the Adapter Class?

Comment: @Code_Yoga, return catagory.length;

Comment: Could you please post the complete code?

Comment: You created a holder,but you did not use it,why

Comment: @warlock, originally i was using holder but same thing was happening, so tried to change the method...

Comment: Sorry my textColor was white ( i didn't set that). Now it is working

Answer (score 0):

Remove your layout_weight attribute from your `TextView`. If you remove sub_catagory.setText(catagory[position]); does "Clothing" appear when you run your app?

Comment: removing layout_weight doesn't work and and also on removing sub_catagory.setText(catagory[position]), "Clothing" doesn't appear, but it is appearing in my Logcat...

Comment: it must be a layout issue then.

Comment: Sorry my textColor was white ( i didn't set that). Now it is working

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer now. I don't know how my textColor was set to White, because i didn't mentioned it. So, change the color to something else and it worked.And it wasted my whole day.

Sorry to disturb you all.